# Adding to a constructor class

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I'm stumped. I have a constructor class that looks like so:

```
    class CClasses
{
    public class CCategoryGroup : List<CCategory>
    {
        public string CTitle { set; get; }
        public string CShortTitle { set; get; }
        public CARESCategoryGroup(string ctitle, string cshorttitle)
        {
            this.CTitle = ctitle;
            this.CShortTitle = cshorttitle;
        }
    };

    public class CCategory
    {
        public int CID { set; get; }
        public string CName { set; get; }
        public ImageSource CIcon { set; get; }
        public string CUrl { set; get; }
        public CCategory(int cid, string cname, ImageSource cicon, string curl)
        {
            this.CID = cid;
            this.CName = cname;
            this.CIcon = cicon;
            this.CUrl = curl;
        }
    };
}
```

I want to add to the constructor portion of the class like so:

```
            //List<CCategoryGroup> ccategory = new List<CCategoryGroup>
        //{
        //    new CCategoryGroup("Dolphin", "Dolphin Group")
        //    {
        //        new CCategory(1, "Bear", ImageSource.FromFile("bear.png")),
        //        new CCategory(2, "Elephant", ImageSource.FromFile("elephant.png")),
        //        new CCategory(3, "Dog", ImageSource.FromFile("dog.png")),
        //        new CCategory(4, "Cat", ImageSource.FromFile("cat.png")),
        //        new CCategory(5, "Squirrel", ImageSource.FromFile("squirrel.png"))
        //    },
```

My problem is I'm trying to add to this class through a loop. So I'm easily able to add the CCategoryGroup with:

```
cCategory.Add(new CCategoryGroup(name, value)
```

How do I add to the CCategory constructor as shown previously?

```
foreach (XElement catelement in xmlDoc.Descendants(xmlNS + "Category"))
        {

            cCategory.Add(new CCategoryGroup(catelement.Element(xmlNS + "Name").Value, catelement.Element(xmlNS + "Name").Value){
                foreach (XElement subcatelement in xmlDoc.Descendants(xmlNS + "SubCategory"))
                {
                    i++;

                    new CCategory(i, subcatelement.Element(xmlNS + "Name").Value, "", subcatelement.Element(xmlNS + "URL").Value);
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm parsing XML and trying to add the results to the class. This does not work, obviously. But is a sample of what I'm trying to do. The first ".add" to cCategoryGroup works great, its the constructor CCategory I cannot add too the way I did in the commented out code.

Comment: What you have would compile is you add the missing 4th parameter to the `CCategory` constructor calls.  Are you looking for something different or does it not work for you?

Comment: Also stop prefacing everything with `C`.  It makes the class and parameter names harder to read and is not necessary in a strongly-typed language.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to run it through a loop. I know the commented out code works, but I'm basically trying to add to a class and the constructor using ".add". How do I add to the constructor using ".add"?

Comment: Then I'm not clear on what you're _trying_ to do.  Can you post something complete that _doesn't_ work so we can understand how to fix it?

Comment: Also is seems like you're trying to add a `CategoryGroup` to a `Category` which is backwards.  Are you trying to add a new category to an existing group?

Comment: I added what doesn't work

Comment: OK I see what you're trying now.  No you can't have a loop within an initializer, but you can just use `Add` within the loop.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I reference the base class and add the new constructor to it, so it resembles the commented code?

Comment: You may want to give a read through of "[Why not inherit from List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use a loop within the collection initializer like that, but you can do it without an initializer:

```
foreach (XElement catelement in xmlDoc.Descendants(xmlNS + "Category"))
{

    CCategoryGroup categoryGroup = new CCategoryGroup(catelement.Element(xmlNS + "Name").Value, catelement.Element(xmlNS + "Name").Value;
    cCategory.Add(categoryGroup);

    foreach (XElement subcatelement in xmlDoc.Descendants(xmlNS + "SubCategory"))
    {
        i++;
        categoryGroup.Add(new CCCategory(i, subcatelement.Element(xmlNS + "Name").Value, "", subcatelement.Element(xmlNS + "URL").Value));
    }
}
```

Note that an initializer just gets translated to a series of `Add` calls by the compiler, so functionally there's no difference between that and adding in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!